# Ubuntu 21.04 slow after login, normal after suspend

Tags: boot, suspend, performance

I have always used Ubuntu 20.04 with no performance issues

From 2021-05-11 after start up the system seemed too slow

To try to solve it I upgraded to 20.10 first, to 21.04 after (groovy procedure), but the problem is still present. Everything is soooo slow

Today afternoon I had a small idea: *suspend the pc*... return from suspension... the system gives good performance as before!

After I turn off the PC and restart the performance problem returns.

I suspend again and the magic happens again: after returning from suspension the system is in "*good performance mode*"

So... why!?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

I searched for this problem but I found people having troubles **after** suspension, not **before**.

What do you need to investigate and (maybe) solve this "upside down" situation?

Thanks in advance.

=== Update 06-07-2021 ===

To the current situation I am still in trouble.

I just need some kind of approach to the problem. I can give you any log or info about the hardware etc.

Ask me, because I don't know what you need.

Thanks

=== Update 06-18-2021 ===

I have not found solutions yet.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks